# ImportError: cannot import name url

Tags: django, python-2.7, uwsgi

I'm upgrading a django app from v1.3 to 1.11.18.
We are running Python v2.7.12 and running an nginx server to serve the pages.

I've been making code changes to account for all of the deprecated methods as a result of the upgrade. So far, so good. After making another run of updates,  I ran into this error notice after starting the server:

```
File "/home/bat/application.com/wsgi.py", line 12, in <module>
   application = get_wsgi_application()
File "./django/core/wsgi.py", line 14, in get_wsgi_application
   return WSGIHandler()
File "./django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 151, in __init__
   self.load_middleware()
File "./django/core/handlers/base.py", line 56, in load_middleware
   mw_class = import_string(middleware_path)
File "./django/utils/module_loading.py", line 20, in import_string
   module = import_module(module_path)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
   __import__(name)
File "./django/middleware/locale.py", line 4, in <module>
   from django.conf.urls.i18n import is_language_prefix_patterns_used
File "./django/conf/urls/i18n.py", line 2, in <module>
   from django.conf.urls import url
ImportError: cannot import name url
```

I'm not sure why I would be getting this error as the code referenced is all core code. It doesn't appear to be referencing any of the project code at all, except for the opening line.

I've double-checked to be sure we do not have any "left over" code sitting in the core django folder: it's clean. We also rebooted the linux server just for kicks: that didn't help either. Beyond that I'm not really sure what else to try?

Any ideas where I might look for a solution to this one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it turns out that the `./django/conf/urls/__init__.py` file is actually MISSING the required `def url()` function. I'm not sure how that didn't get noticed before by anyone, as the core code clearly calls that `url` function all over the place.

To resolve that issue, I downloaded Django v1.10.x and copied the `def url(...)` function from the v1.10.x code into the `django/conf/urls/__init__.py` file and everything worked as expected.

I do realize that I modified a core file, but I wasn't sure how to get around the issue otherwise. This 1.x branch of Django is not under active development, so I figure that's probably okay.